# Display text base on condition (crystal report)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, c#-3.0

I want to display fields of 'Short description'  if field of 'Long description' is not blank.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write click on your textobject or database field object => Format Object

In "Common" Tab of this new windows there is a field called Suppress, click on the button to the right of this field with the text "X-2". This will add a new formula, you'll need to return a boolean to set when your field will be suppress ( not displayed or not )

That's all.

Comment: ty, new to Crystal Reports and I have no idea how stuff works! :-)